# How can I delete the yonguer musician in a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table musician_groups:

[image: Table musician groups]

This table is sorted but I need to delete the duplicated titles.

In the table, I have 4 Master of puppets I need to get only the first one and delete the others.

I need something like this:

[image: Result expected]

Cliff Burton is on the top because is older than Kirk Hammet.

Someone can illuminate me?

Best regards,

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query:

```
delete from musician_groups 
where id not in (SELECT * from (SELECT MIN(n.id) FROM musician_groups n GROUP BY n.title) x )
```

Comment: your sub-select can be simplified to `not in (select min(n.id) from ...)` not need for another layer of queries

Answer (score 0):

"first" is not well defined in SQL.  But you can keep one of the names, such as the first alphabetically:

```
delete from musician_groups mg
    where mg.name > (select max(mg2.name)
                     from musician_groups mg2
                     where mg2.title = mg.title
                    );
```

If you do have an `id` column or another way to choose the row you want to keep, then you can use that.

If you have a large table, deleting large numbers of rows is expensive.  Often, the fastest method is to re-insert into the table:

```
create table temp_musician_groups as
     select distinct on (title) mg.*
     from musician_groups mg
     order by title, name;

truncate table musician_groups;  -- back up the table first!

insert into musician_groups
    select *
    from temp_musician_groups;
```